# How to check which directory authorities assign/withhold which flags to my relays

Tags: configuration, relays, directory, connection, torcheck

Continuing the discussion from [[tor-relays] Relay MIGHTYWANG consensus issues and loss of STABLE flag](https://forum.torproject.org/t/tor-relays-relay-mightywang-consensus-issues-and-loss-of-stable-flag/282):

[image]

[quote="Mighty_Wang, post:1, topic:282"]
So next I checked the consensus and I see that around half of the directory authorities seem to be not assigning the stable flag. See attached screenshot showing current consensus.
[/quote]

[image]

How can I check this precise info about my middle relays:
[0C4D7C61271C32DFBD0DF4A0296E4CE1BA2E952A](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/0C4D7C61271C32DFBD0DF4A0296E4CE1BA2E952A)
and
[6AE0E65677643B9DB60390AAC0AF544114825FD4](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/6AE0E65677643B9DB60390AAC0AF544114825FD4)  ?

Also here, in [this thread](https://forum.torproject.org/t/tor-relays-loss-of-stable-flag/662) the relay operator writes about a possibility of checking the info about which directory authority assigned which flag to the specific tor relay.
[quote="tor-relays, post:3, topic:662"]
The DAs which are witholding the flag are tor26, gabelmoo, dannenberg, maatuska and bastet.
[/quote]

[image]

How would I check this information ??

### How to check which directory authorities assign/withhold which flags to my relays?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the consensus data, all the actions are digitally signed. What exact data/votes/actions is broadcasted - it was changing from time to time due to the protocol versions, but as far as I remember this data is broadcasted and it's even a python trigger can be used to analyze it via Stem library in nearly a real time.

Update: forgot a link :) Happy new Year and Merry Christmas! https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/persisting_a_consensus.html  and https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/compare_flags.html